# Does the Schottky Barrier only happen at Metal Semiconductor Interfaces?

Tags: solid-state-physics, terminology, semiconductor-physics

Most references that I have come across refer to the Schottky Barrier in the setting of Metal and Semiconductor Interface. Would it be correct to use the term Schottky Barrier to refer to the mismatch in energy levels in other settings (e.g. semiconductor-seminconductor)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes word usage is well-standardized, for example the words *work* and *heat* are well defined.  Sometimes it is not, and one must be careful to understand what is meant by context.  I don't believe that *Schottky Barrier* is as well standardized as *work*, but I think it's usage leans strongly toward the classic metal/semiconductor interface.   I suppose it could be used in other contexts,  but doing so risks confusion.  So when reading, make sure you understand the context.  When writing, avoid using it for anything other than a metal/semiconductor interface.